# Emulate a USB hub with arduino

Tags: arduino, usb

How would one go about using an arduino mega ADK to emulate a USB hub with a mouse and keyboard attached? I found oodles of information from [vusb](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) and this [related project](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/virtual-usb-keyboard), but nothing about emulating a USB hub.

Comment: out of curiousity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I haven't seen it done before but should be possible as long you keep it low-speed. Just read USB spec about protocol diffrences between host and hub and modify vusb or any other stack based on that. I do not see any reason why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @vicatcu I'm using a smartphone as a keyboard and mouse using an arduino as an intermediary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you realy want to emulate a hub with two devices I don't thin an AVR is up to that task. Maybe take an off-the-shelve USB hub chip.

But I think you can emulate a composite device (mouse and keyboard in one device).

Comment: +1 for this. If the requirement is "emulate 1 keyboard and 1 mouse via 1 USB cable" then this is the way to go. For a quick solution Jeffrey might also consider to wire two arduinos to an actual hub and programm 1 arduino as a mouse and the other as a keyboard. That might simplify the software development.

Comment: I wasn't aware of composite devices, I'll look more into that.